# Creating android emulator using android-studio version 2022.3.1 in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, ubuntu-22.04

Failing to create android emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUuZ8.png)

I just installed android studio (giraffe version), which is recommended for Ubuntu 22.04. I am trying to create an emulator but the "Next" button is grayed out even after selecting the preferred image. I selected multiple images but no change detected. Any way to go past this?

Answer (score 0):

you must download the version you want to use.

[image]

**LinkVideo with similar problem**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cII8kgctYM